# FAVAR impulse responses

Tags: r, pca, factor-analysis, vector-autoregression, impulse-response

I am doing FAVAR analysis with two-step principal component method. I have estimated VAR including factors obtained using principal component analysis and assumption that variables can be divided to slow- and fast-moving variables. I can draw the impulse response functions for my factors but my problem is that I do not know how to get impulse responses for the variables of interest.

What I first thought, was to multiply impulse responses of factors by rotation matrix obtained from original principal component analysis using the whole data set. Using R I would do it like this:

`t( t(irf.factors$x %*% t(pca$rotation)) * pca$scale + pca$center)`

But does this make any sense? This is just something I have concluded. I have not seen any instructions. Should I use rotation matrix obtained from pca for the whole data set or for the slow-moving variables or something else? I have been following Bernanke, Boivin and Eliasz (2005) but they do not explain this very clearly.

Edit:

Another option that came to my mind, is to regress original variables on factors (that I am using in my FAVAR). So I would get an estimate of the relationship between factors and variables. Using these estimated coefficients I could form the impulse response functions of the variables of interest. Does this seem right?

Comment: I'm sorry for writting you here, couldn't figure out how to write you a direct message. Could you please share your R code with 2-step estimation process if it is possible. I'm trying to use FAVAR for prediction task and still unsure whether am I doing it right. Thanks in advance.